# Data Analytics: Group Value Streams acc. to Similarity

Tags: python, stream, analytics, production

My colleague and I (both mechanical engineers) like to learn python and solve new interesting problems.

**Our problem:** We want to analyze the value streams of our components (> 50.000) and group them according to the similary of their value streams.

To give an example - Lets say we have three materials A,B and C with the following data:

A = [610384, 521056, 112200, 194825633, 45]

B = [10389, 462, 1028503]

C = [10389, 462, 1028503, 112200, 45, 194825633]

Each array symbolizes one value stream, every element one machine in the value stream. A for example has to run over 5 machines to get produced. "610384" is the number of the first machine in the value stream. As you can see A and B are similar to C because B is a 100% substream of C, but A contains 3 of the same machines but in another sequence.

**Constraints:**

- numbers have no meaning at all -> can not be compared based on their size or anything
- arrays have different lenghts, elements as well
- arrays can contain subarrays or be in different order etc. Everything is possible (We are expolring the data set).
- We can rate on 4 levels, from top to down level: technologie, process description, process description detail, machine number -> meaning: machine numbers 10389 and 462 are not equal at all, but both machine are used to "drill" holes. So level 2 (process description) would be equal. So, we could use this to rate them not 100% or 0% equal, but maybe give them a 30% similarity at this machine (not the whole value stream!).

Example for 4 levels: Manual Drilling (1) -> Drilling (2) -> Drilling holes 90 degree (3) -> machine number 462 (4)

**Issues:**

1. How should we rate every value stream to each other? Taking different lengths etc. into account
2. How can we cluster given ratings in useful ways?

Is there a suitable algorithm we should use? Do we need to define rules on our own? If so, can you recommend any reading to do so?

**Our goal:** Group similar value streams, so we could see our value stream highways and see if machines should be moved around.

PS: it's an adjusted repost from Reddit r/analytics

Answer (score 0):

This might me the partial solution,

I have used following abbr. for ratings :

md - Manual drilling
,d - Drilling
,30 or 45 or 60 - Drilling holes at certain degree

1) machine 10389 rating : 'md-d-90-10389'  # manual drill + drilling + 90 degree

2) machine 462 rating : 'md-d-45-462' # manual drill + drilling + 45 degree

```
import fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import process
matches = fuzzywuzzy.process.extract('md-d-90-10389',['md-d-45-462'],scorer=fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
print(matches[0][1], '%')
```

Output:
    33 %

There are many ways you can do it like Cosine similarity or Jaccard similarity.
We can try this at first place.

Then we keep only one machine out of two if similarity is greater than 80%.
e.g: Lets just take only 2 value streams A and C. if 521056 and 10389 have similarity of 80% then we can discard other only for simplification purposes.
Let's keep 10389.

A = [610384, 10389, 112200, 194825633, 45] # replaced 521056 to 10389

C = [10389, 462, 1028503, 112200, 45, 194825633]

Then we can check Cosine similarities between A and C to rate closeness of value streams.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, is your answer not making the mistake that machines with similar numbers are rated closer then ones with different numbers?
To give an example:
A = md-d-90-99999999
B = md-d-90-10389
C = tt-x-50-10388

Here, B to C could be more similar due to a high similarity of the machine number (what is saying nothing). But B and C should be rated very unsimilar because the technologies are totally different.

Comment: One solution could be to exclude machine names during rating comparison phase. First will store their actual names in dictionary to have reference and then remove machine name for matching operation.
A = md-d-90, B = md-d-90, C = tt-x-50 , Now in this scenario B and C will be entirely dissimilar.

Comment: Does above solution in comment solves your problem?